# Using ls to list directories and their total sizes

Tags: linux, unix

Is it possible to use `ls` in Unix to list the total size of a sub-directory and all its contents as opposed to the usual `4K` that (I assume) is just the directory file itself?

```
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x  6 *** *** 4.0K 2009-06-19 10:10 branches
drwxrwxr-x 13 *** *** 4.0K 2009-06-19 10:52 tags
drwxrwxr-x 16 *** *** 4.0K 2009-06-19 10:02 trunk
```

After scouring the man pages I'm coming up empty.

Comment: you want to use du -s instead

Comment: In a search for ducks: `alias ducks='du -cksh * | sort -hr | head -n 15'`

Comment: Note that the `-h` option in `alias ducks='du -cksh * | sort -hr | head -n 15'` and the `-c` option to `du` are mostly non-portable GNU extensions to the POSIX-standard [`du`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/du.html) and [`sort`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sort.html) utilities.  Without the `-h` option, `sort` has to be invoked with the `-n` option to do *numeric* sorting, simplified:  `du -sk * | sort -n`.

Comment: Leaving out `-r` from `sort` and not passing the results through `head` (or `tail`, as the case may be) emits the entire results to the terminal, largest last.  Which is very useful in an interactive session.  Beware also that `*` will skip files and directories that start with `.` such as `.m2`.

Answer (score 2121, accepted):

Try something like:

```
du -sh *
```

short version of:

```
du --summarize --human-readable *
```

#### Explanation:

`du`: **D**isk **U**sage

`-s`: Display a summary for each specified file.  (Equivalent to `-d 0`)

`-h`: "Human-readable" output.  Use unit suffixes: **B**yte, **K**ibibyte (KiB), **M**ebibyte (MiB), **G**ibibyte (GiB), **T**ebibyte (TiB) and **P**ebibyte (PiB). (BASE2)

Comment: Also -c (produce a grand total) is nice.

Comment: du --max-depth 1 only shows file/folder sizes of 1 deep in the tree, no more clutter and easy to find large folders within a folder.

Comment: how to include hidden files too ?

Comment: it's `du -h -d 1` on OSX

Comment: @Zak in zsh you can use the `*(D)` to match hidden (**d**ot) files alongside with normal files. When using bash, you could use `* .[!.]*` to match both.

Comment: To get a clear picture of where space goes, `du -sch * .[!.]* | sort -rh` is great (show a sorted output)
On mac do:
`brew install coreutils` and then `du -sch * .[!.]* | gsort -rh`

Comment: All of those answers mention du. but the result can be wrong. sum of disk usage is not the same as the sum of each file size. If I have a 100 1-byte files on a directory, du -hs <dirname> shows 400k, not 100 bytes ... (just tried it on linux)

Comment: `--summary` is now `--summarize`  or (`-s`)

Comment: To sort, could also do `du -sh * | sort -h` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19864850/1526703) answer below

Comment: this command always takes ages for me to run...an alternatve? This is why I was looking for a Q with ls like the title says.

Answer (score 470):

`du -sk * | sort -n` will sort the folders by size. Helpful when looking to clear space..

or `du -sh * | sort -h` used when human-readable mode

Comment: Append a `| tail -r` to sort by largest first.

Comment: `sort -rn` sorts things in reverse numerical order. `sort -rn | head -n 10` will show only the top few, if that's of any interest.

Comment: `sort -rh` will work nicely with `du -cksh *` as it sorts human-readable units.

Comment: @Sebi -h is not a valid parameter for sort on a Mac unfortunately

Comment: @Sebi also the -c is not necessary, `du -ksh | sort -rn` is the same as `du -cksh | sort -rn`. Just as `du -ksh` is the same as `du -cksh`.

Comment: Why is the -k necessary ? In the documentation it says: -k                    like --block-size=1K , does this influence the precision?

Comment: this command always takes ages for me to run...an alternatve? This is why I was looking for a Q with ls like the title says.

Answer (score 152):

```
du -sh * | sort -h
```

This will be displayed in human readable format.

Comment: More about `sort -h` here: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sort-invocation It's especially there for sorting `103K`, `102M`, `1.1G` etc. This should be available on a lot of systems nowadays, but not all.

Comment: duh -shm * | sort -n ?

Comment: works great, one small addition `du -sh * | sort -rh` (-r for listing bigger folders first)

Comment: To include hidden files/directories; `du -sh $(ls -A) | sort -h`

Comment: this command always takes ages for me to run...an alternatve? This is why I was looking for a Q with ls like the title says.

Answer (score 70):

To list the largest directories from the current directory in human readable format:

`du -sh * | sort -hr`

A better way to restrict number of rows can be

`du -sh * | sort -hr | head -n10`

Where you can increase the suffix of `-n` flag to restrict the number of rows listed

Sample:

```
[~]$ du -sh * | sort -hr
48M app
11M lib
6.7M    Vendor
1.1M    composer.phar
488K    phpcs.phar
488K    phpcbf.phar
72K doc
16K nbproject
8.0K    composer.lock
4.0K    README.md
```

It makes it more convenient to read :)

Comment: this command always takes ages for me to run...an alternatve? This is why I was looking for a Q with ls like the title says.

Answer (score 36):

To display it in `ls -lh` format, use:

```sh
(du -sh ./*; ls -lh --color=no) | awk '{ if($1 == "total") {X = 1} else if (!X) {SIZES[$2] = $1} else { sub($5 "[ ]*", sprintf("%-7s ", SIZES["./" $9]), $0); print $0} }'
```

Awk code explained:

```php
if($1 == "total") { // Set X when start of ls is detected
  X = 1 
} else if (!X) { // Until X is set, collect the sizes from `du`
  SIZES[$2] = $1
} else {
  // Replace the size on current current line (with alignment)
  sub($5 "[ ]*", sprintf("%-7s ", SIZES["./" $9]), $0); 
  print $0
}
```

Sample output:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root 4.0K    Feb 12 16:43 cgi-bin
drwxrws--- 6 root     www  20M     Feb 18 11:07 document_root
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root 1.3M    Feb 18 00:18 icons
drwxrwsr-x 2 localusr www  8.0K    Dec 27 01:23 passwd
```

Comment: any way to sort this output? Also for anyone on mac this works brilliantly if you remove `--color=no`

Comment: @anon58192932 You can pipe the output to `sort --key=5,5h` for sorting 'human readable units' from fifth column

Comment: returns `sort: stray character in field spec: invalid field specification `5,5h'`. I really hate macs sometimes =\

Comment: @anon58192932 You can ask a question relating to mac, I'm sure there is someone who could help. This question is tagged as GNU/[tag:linux]

Comment: is there a way to preserve color using this answer?

Comment: formatted result:    (du -sh ./*; ls -lh --color=no) | awk '{ if($1 == "total") {X = 1} else if (!X) {SIZES[$2] = $1} else { printf("%11s %4s %-6s %-6s %7s %3s %2s %5s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, SIZES["./" $9], $6, $7, $8, $9) } }' | sort --key=5,5h

Answer (score 28):

**`ncdu` (ncurses `du`)**

This awesome CLI utility allows you to easily find the large files and directories (recursive total size) interactively.

For example, from inside the root of [a well known open source project](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/v5.0) we do:

```
sudo apt install ncdu
ncdu
```

The outcome its:

[image]

Then, I enter down and right on my keyboard to go into the `/drivers` folder, and I see:

[image]

`ncdu` only calculates file sizes recursively once at startup for the entire tree, so it is efficient. This way don't have to recalculate sizes as you move inside subdirectories as you try to determine what the disk hog is.

"Total disk usage" vs "Apparent size" is analogous to `du`, and I have explained it at: [why is the output of `du` often so different from `du -b`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694741/why-is-the-output-of-du-often-so-different-from-du-b/55514003#55514003)

Project homepage: https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu

Related questions:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67806/how-to-recursively-find-the-amount-stored-in-directory/67808
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/tracking-down-where-disk-space-has-gone-on-linux
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/57603/how-to-list-recursive-file-sizes-of-files-and-directories-in-a-directory
- https://serverfault.com/questions/43296/how-does-one-find-which-files-are-taking-up-80-of-the-space-on-a-linux-webserve

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04.

**Ubuntu list root**

You likely want:

```
ncdu --exclude-kernfs -x /
```

where:

- `-x` stops crossing of filesystem barriers
- `--exclude-kernfs` skips special filesystems like `/sys`

**MacOS 10.15.5 list root**

To properly list root `/` on that system, I also needed `--exclude-firmlinks`, e.g.:

```
brew install ncdu
cd /
ncdu --exclude-firmlinks
```

otherwise it seemed to go into some link infinite loop, likely due to: https://www.swiftforensics.com/2019/10/macos-1015-volumes-firmlink-magic.html

The things we learn for love.

**`ncdu` non-interactive usage**

Another cool feature of `ncdu` is that you can first dump the sizes in a JSON format, and later reuse them.

For example, to generate the file run:

```
ncdu -o ncdu.json
```

and then examine it interactively with:

```
ncdu -f ncdu.json
```

This is very useful if you are dealing with a very large and slow filesystem like NFS.

This way, you can first export only once, which can take hours, and then explore the files, quit, explore again, etc.

The output format is just JSON, so it is easy to reuse it with other programs as well, e.g.:

```
ncdu -o -  | python -m json.tool | less
```

reveals a simple directory tree data structure:

```
[
    1,
    0,
    {
        "progname": "ncdu",
        "progver": "1.12",
        "timestamp": 1562151680
    },
    [
        {
            "asize": 4096,
            "dev": 2065,
            "dsize": 4096,
            "ino": 9838037,
            "name": "/work/linux-kernel-module-cheat/submodules/linux"
        },
        {
            "asize": 1513,
            "dsize": 4096,
            "ino": 9856660,
            "name": "Kbuild"
        },
        [
            {
                "asize": 4096,
                "dsize": 4096,
                "ino": 10101519,
                "name": "net"
            },
            [
                {
                    "asize": 4096,
                    "dsize": 4096,
                    "ino": 11417591,
                    "name": "l2tp"
                },
                {
                    "asize": 48173,
                    "dsize": 49152,
                    "ino": 11418744,
                    "name": "l2tp_core.c"
                },
```

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I agree, ncdu is the way to go... but do you know if it is possible to search the JSON file? That is, get the full path of a specific file/folder.

Comment: @FGV I don't think ncdu can output that, one possibility would be to hack up a simple python script that parses the JSON.

Comment: The things I want to say, Peace-

Answer (score 22):

Put this shell function declaration in your shell initialization scripts:

```
function duls {
    paste <( du -hs -- "$@" | cut -f1 ) <( ls -ldf -- "$@" )
}
```

I called it `duls` because it shows the output from both `du` and `ls` (in that order):

```
$ duls
210M    drwxr-xr-x  21 kk  staff  714 Jun 15 09:32 .

$ duls *
 36K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff    35147 Jun  9 16:03 COPYING
8.0K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff     6962 Jun  9 16:03 INSTALL
 28K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff    24816 Jun 10 13:26 Makefile
4.0K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff       75 Jun  9 16:03 Makefile.am
 24K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff    24473 Jun 10 13:26 Makefile.in
4.0K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff     1689 Jun  9 16:03 README
120K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff   121585 Jun 10 13:26 aclocal.m4
684K    drwxr-xr-x   7 kk  staff      238 Jun 10 13:26 autom4te.cache
128K    drwxr-xr-x   8 kk  staff      272 Jun  9 16:03 build
 60K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff    60083 Jun 10 13:26 config.log
 36K    -rwxr-xr-x   1 kk  staff    34716 Jun 10 13:26 config.status
264K    -rwxr-xr-x   1 kk  staff   266637 Jun 10 13:26 configure
8.0K    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff     4280 Jun 10 13:25 configure.ac
7.0M    drwxr-xr-x   8 kk  staff      272 Jun 10 13:26 doc
2.3M    drwxr-xr-x  28 kk  staff      952 Jun 10 13:26 examples
6.2M    -rw-r--r--   1 kk  staff  6505797 Jun 15 09:32 mrbayes-3.2.7-dev.tar.gz
 11M    drwxr-xr-x  42 kk  staff     1428 Jun 10 13:26 src

$ duls doc
7.0M    drwxr-xr-x  8 kk  staff  272 Jun 10 13:26 doc

$ duls [bM]*
 28K    -rw-r--r--  1 kk  staff  24816 Jun 10 13:26 Makefile
4.0K    -rw-r--r--  1 kk  staff     75 Jun  9 16:03 Makefile.am
 24K    -rw-r--r--  1 kk  staff  24473 Jun 10 13:26 Makefile.in
128K    drwxr-xr-x  8 kk  staff    272 Jun  9 16:03 build
```

Explanation:

The `paste` utility creates columns from its input according to the specification that you give it.  Given two input files, it puts them side by side, with a tab as separator.

We give it the output of `du -hs -- "$@" | cut -f1` as the first file (input stream really) and the output of `ls -ldf -- "$@"` as the second file.

In the function, `"$@"` will evaluate to the list of all command line arguments, each in double quotes. It will therefore understand globbing characters and path names with spaces etc.

The double minuses (`--`) signals the end of command line options to `du` and `ls`.  Without these, saying `duls -l` would confuse `du` and any option for `du` that `ls` doesn't have would confuse `ls` (and the options that exist in both utilities might not mean the same thing, and it would be a pretty mess).

The `cut` after `du` simply cuts out the first column of the `du -hs` output (the sizes).

I decided to put the `du` output on the left, otherwise I would have had to manage a wobbly right column (due to varying lengths of file names).

The command will not accept command line flags.

This has been tested in both `bash` and in `ksh93`. It will not work with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: That's nice. Permissions *and* sizes on one line

Comment: I've been using the hack `paste <(echo ""; du -sh $(ls) | cut -f 1) <(ls -l)`.

Comment: Note that this will usually fail on non-default-ls-ordered inputs, e.g. `duls $(ls -tr)`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq That should be trivially fixable by adding `-f` to the invocation of `ls` in my code. Your suggested command would quite likely have issus with any filename containing spaces, tabs or newlines, as well as with names starting with a dash.

Answer (score 21):

The command you want is 'du -sk' du = "disk usage"

The -k flag gives you output in kilobytes, rather than the du default of disk sectors (512-byte blocks).

The -s flag will only list things in the top level directory (i.e., the current directory, by default, or the directory specified on the command line).  It's odd that du has the opposite behavior of ls in this regard.  By default du will recursively give you the disk usage of each sub-directory.  In contrast, ls will only give list files in the specified directory.  (ls -R gives you recursive behavior.)

Comment: Tried this on the root directory, it still tries to list subdirectories, resulting in a lot of messages.

Answer (score 19):

**Ordered** **list** of folders and files (descendant order, according to size) in a directory:

```
du -skh * | sort -hr
```

Including hidden files:

```
du -skh .??* * | sort -hr
```

**Explanation:**

The command `du` estimates disk usage.

- `-s` summary, as in, not recursive, only files/folders at this level.
- `-kh` human readable, as in GB, MB, KB, etc...
- `.??*` names staring with dot `.` that are 3 or more characters long (excluding `.` and `..` links).
- `*` all files/folders not starting with `.`.

`du` shows smaller sizes first by default. And we call it for two sets of files (hidden and normal), so we need to `sort` the result again combining results.

- `-h` reorders considering human readable characters (human-numeric, like GB, MB, etc..).
- `-r` reverse the order.

Note. Other answers contain most of these options but scattered along different ones and none here explore how to easily include hidden files/folders.

Answer (score 11):

```
du -h --max-depth=1 . | sort -n -r
```

Comment: du -h -d 1 for maximum depth of 1. Short form.

Comment: du -hd1 = short form ;)

Comment: `$ du -h -d 1` perfecto thanks

Answer (score 8):

I always use `du -sk` (`-k` flag showing file size in kilobytes) instead.

Comment: this should be a comment, providing additional info to the more correct and better explained accepted answer by @molf. It should not be considered an answer on it's own

Answer (score 6):

This is one I like

*update*: I didnt like the previous one because it didn't show files in the current directory, it only listed directories.

Example output for `/var` on ubuntu:

`sudo du -hDaxd1 /var | sort -h | tail -n10`

```
4.0K    /var/lock
4.0K    /var/run
4.0K    /var/www
12K     /var/spool
3.7M    /var/backups
33M     /var/log
45M     /var/webmin
231M    /var/cache
1.4G    /var/lib
1.7G    /var
```

Answer (score 4):

To display current directory's files and subdirectories sizes recursively:

```
du -h .
```

To display the **same size information** but **without** printing their sub directories recursively (which can be a huge list), just use the *--max-depth* option:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 .
```

Answer (score 4):

du -sch * in the same directory.

Answer (score 3):

These are all great suggestions, but the one I use is:

```
du -ksh * | sort -n -r
```

`-ksh` makes sure the files and folders are listed in a human-readable format and in megabytes, kilobytes, etc. Then you sort them numerically and reverse the sort so it puts the bigger ones first.

The only downside to this command is that the computer does not know that Gigabyte is bigger than Megabyte so it will only sort by numbers and you will often find listings like this:

```
120K
12M
4G
```

Just be careful to look at the unit.

This command also works on the Mac (whereas `sort -h` does not for example).

Comment: If you remove the ``-h`` flag from the ``du`` command you cut that downside

Comment: Or you can use `-h` instead of `-n` in sort as well.

Comment: or just pipe it through a grep G

Answer (score 3):

```
du -S
```

*du* have another useful option:  `-S, --separate-dirs` telling *du* not include size of subdirectories - handy on some occasions.

Example 1 - shows *only* the file sizes in a directory:

```
du -Sh  * 
3,1G    10/CR2
280M    10
```

Example 2 - shows the file sizes and subdirectories in directory:

```
du -h  * 
3,1G    10/CR2 
3,4G    10
```

Answer (score 3):

du -sm * | sort -nr

Output by size

Answer (score 3):

If you want more control over the `size` that you want to list the directories over, you can use the `threshold` (`-t`) switch as in:

```
$ du -ht 1000000000 | sort --reverse
```

`du` - `d`isk `u`sage
  `h`  - human readable format
  `t`  - threshold size

Here, we want to list all directories which are greater than 1GB in size.

```
$ du -ht 1G | sort --reverse
```

---

**Explanation**:

Units that are [described in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terabyte) follows:

> K, M, G, T, P, E, Z, Y (powers of 1024)  or
>    KB, MB, GB, TB, PB, EB, ZB, YB (powers of 1000).

Answer (score 2):

look at `du` command for that

Answer (score 2):

just a warning, if you want to compare sizes of files. du produces different results depending on file system, block size, ... .

It may happen that the size of the files is different, e.g. comparing the same directory on your local hard-disk and a USB mass storage device. I use the following script, including ls to sum up the directory size. The result in in bytes taking all sub directories into account.

```
echo "[GetFileSize.sh] target directory: \"$1\""

iRetValue=0

uiLength=$(expr length "$1")
if [ $uiLength -lt 2 ]; then
  echo "[GetFileSize.sh] invalid target directory: \"$1\" - exiting!"
  iRetValue=-1
else
  echo "[GetFileSize.sh] computing size of files..."

  # use ls to compute total size of all files - skip directories as they may
  # show different sizes, depending on block size of target disk / file system
  uiTotalSize=$(ls -l -R $1 | grep -v ^d | awk '{total+=$5;} END {print total;}')
  uiLength=$(expr length "$uiTotalSize")
  if [ $uiLength -lt 1 ]; then
    uiTotalSize=0
  fi
  echo -e "[GetFileSize.sh] total target file size: \"$uiTotalSize\""

fi

exit "$iRetValue"
```

Answer (score 1):

For a while, I used Nautilus (on Gnome desktop on RHEL 6.0) to  delete files on my home folder instead of using the `rm` command in bash. As a result, the total size shown by

```
du -sh
```

did not match the sum of disk usage of each sub-directory, when I used

```
du -sh *
```

It took me a while to realise Nautilus sends the deleted files to its Trash folder, and that folder is not listed in `du -sh *` command. So, just wanted to share this, in case somebody faced the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, best way is to use this command:

```
du -h -x / | sort -hr >> /home/log_size.txt
```

Then you will be able to get all sizes folders over all your server. Easy to help to you to find the biggest sizes.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` `du -hsx 2>/dev/null *`

```
0       bin
4.0K    boot
0       dev
9.0M    etc
6.5M    home
824K    init
0       lib
0       lib32
0       lib64
0       libx32
16K     lost+found
4.0K    media
4.0K    mnt
4.0K    opt
0       proc
61M     root
36K     run
0       sbin
4.0K    srv
0       sys
4.0K    tmp
2.2G    usr
4.9G    var
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue similar to what Martin Wilde described, in my case comparing the same directory on two different servers after mirroring with rsync.

Instead of using a script I added the `-b` flag to the `du` which counts the size in bytes and as far as I can determine eliminated the differences on the two servers. You still can use `-s -h` to get a comprehensible output.

Answer (score 0):

place in init script like .bashrc ... adjust def as needed.

```
duh() {
  # shows disk utilization for a path and depth level
  path="${1:-$PWD}"
  level="${2:-0}"
  du "$path" -h --max-depth="$level"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note here that `du` gives you disk usage. Different machines can use different block sizes, so on one machine a block could be 4096 bytes and another machine could contain block sizes of 2048. If I put 10 1 byte files in a machine using 4096 bytes blocks and 10 1 byte file in a machine using 2048 bytes blocks, `du -h` would report ~40k and ~20k respectively.

If you want to know the size of all the files in a directory, for each directory you can do something like:

```sh
for x in ./*;
do
    if [[ -f "$x" ]]; then
        ls -al "$x"
    fi
done | awk '{print $6}' | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'
```

This would give you the total size of all the files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec du --apparent-size --max-depth=0 --null '{}' ';' |\
  sort -k1 -nr --zero-terminated |\
  cut -f2 --zero-terminated |\
  xargs --null -n 1 du -h --apparent-size --max-depth=0
```

Features:

- Since Linux filenames can have newlines or blank spaces, we use null character to delimit file/directory names.
- We sort the files/directories by their size.
- We use `--apparent-size` with `du` to get a behavior similar to `ls`.

Answer (score -1):

Retrieve only the size in bytes, from ls.

```
ls -ltr | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Comment: This answer does not work. You can [try it here](https://onlinegdb.com/AHF2vHYus). For a directory `dir` containing a 1MB file, `ls ...` reports `8` and `ls ... dir | ...` reports `1024`.

Answer (score -3):

type "ls -ltrh /path_to_directory"

Comment: `ls` does not list the size of a directory's contents (rather it gives the size of the directory *file*, which only stores the names of the files it contains, and so is very small), so it is not useful for this purpose.