# Cloning only a subdirectory with Git

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

I have a Git repository that includes subdirectories. Example *dirA*/*dirB*.

Is there a way to do a `git clone` on a Unix server to pull only files from a subdirectory (*dirB*)?

Is there some other Git command other than *clone* that will do this?

How do I Git a specific file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only

Comment: [Simple answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2466755/287948)

Comment: Already answered. Updated 2022 answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73254328/4184651

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to clone only parts of your repository, you should look at [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

The subdirectory is managed by a specific git repository and is referenced in the main repository as a submodule.

When you clone the main repository, the submodules are not automatically cloned.

Comment: When you clone the main repository, the submodules are not automatically cloned? why? it absurd:(

Comment: This does not answer the question. It basically says: "I don't have an answer for your question, so I'll answer another question, because that's what I think you should do instead."

Comment: @EduardoBezerra Exactly. I would prefer an answer and then a comment on alternatives. Check Bruno Thomas answer

Comment: `Git sparse` might be a better option. Have a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/431967) answer.

Answer (score 35):

Suppose your project is in a dir called `project`, and you want only those commits which touch `project/dirB`.

Then:

```
git clone project/ subproject/
cd subproject
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter dirB HEAD
```

`subproject` will now contain the git history which touches `dirB`.

Comment: this worked great to grab only the initial sub-directory content, but when I executed a subsequent `pull` it merged with the original branch...

Comment: If you don't want the git history as a whole, add the `--depth 0` flag.

Answer (score 19):

Cf *[git-archive(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html)*.

With a shell command:

```
git archive --remote=<repo_url> <branch> <path> | tar xvf -
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share a workaround. You can clone the entire repo, and then create a symulink for subdirectory:

```
mkdir <repo_dir>
cd <repo_dir>
git clone <repo_url>
ln -s <sub_dir> <your_location_where_you_want_to_checkout_sub_dir>
```

Again, this is not a solution - just a workaround. You will still clone the whole repo, and you can pull the changes only from . However, this was useful in some case of mine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really cloning, but if you just want a part of a project to start a new repo with, go into your repo and

```
git archive master <subdir> | tar -x -C /somewhere/else
```

Then go /somewhere/else and start a new repo there.

Answer (score 0):

Git works on the repository level. You will not be able to select only a subdirectory. If the repository that you are interested in has a web interface, you might be able to navigate to your subdirectory and grab it.

Comment: Yes, git works on a repository, however, the desire to have a light checkout is high due to data mobility challenges.