# Deploying /dist folder of repo with Git post-update hook

Tags: git, deployment, githooks

This is a post-update hook (took it from  [here](http://blog.g-design.net/post/60019471157/managing-and-deploying-wordpress-with-git)), I've set in the bare repository on a server. It deploys the entire repository to the path at `GIT_WORK_TREE`:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/you/live/files
git checkout -f
```

How to setup a post-update hook in Git in order to deploy only the dist/ folder of the repository?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, base one this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19594074/220710) :

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/to/you/live/files
git archive --remote=<repo_url> <branch> dist | tar xvf -
```

Comment: thanks! got some more info about that [here](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/deploying-a-git-repository-to-a-remote-server). I got some headache with the Git syntax though, and then I ultimately realized that I don't need a bare repository on the server and I just solved my problem doing a `rsync` in the dist/ folder.