# Can I restore my source files with only the .git folder?

Tags: git

I had a problem with my cloud file server and I don't have the source of my project anymore... Is it possible to restore the full project with only the .git folder ?

If it's possible, how can I do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a working copy of a bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450245/getting-a-working-copy-of-a-bare-repository)

Answer (score 3):

Open the Git bash and navigate to the folder containing the `.git` folder/file.  If the prompt shows some branch, then it's looking good for you.  You should then be able to just checkout a branch, e.g.

```
git checkout master
```

The `.git` folder should store all the state of that particular local repository.

Comment: Doesn't the OP need to clone the repo?

Comment: @Liam If the OP has the ability to `git clone` into some folder, then he doesn't need the `.git` folder in the first place.

Comment: Just tested. Seems `checkout` and `clone` essentially both uncompress the repo. You could clone a `.git` folder but this is likely easier TBH

Comment: @Liam: I'm not sure what you mean by "uncompress the repo". The repository remains unchanged; when you check out a commit, what you are doing is copying the commit's tree content (saved snapshot) into both your *index* (aka *staging-area*, there is a main one for every repository plus one auxiliary one per `git worktree add`-ed work-tree) and your *work-tree*. The files in the work-tree are in ordinary format, so "decompressed" fits well here, but that's for *one commit*, not the entire repo...

Comment: @Liam - In addition to torek's notes, I would point out that the reason `clone` creates a work tree (by default) is because after duplicating the repository, it performs a `checkout` (by default).  Either way it's the checkout that's doing the work, so it usually won't make sense to do a clone just for that side-effect.