# Git merge with force overwrite

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a branch called `demo` which I need to merge with `master` branch. I can get the desired result with following commands:

```
git pull origin demo
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge demo
git push origin master
```

My only concern is, *if there are any merge issues*, I want to tell `git` to overwrite changes in `master` branch without giving me merge prompt. So basically changes in `demo` branch should automatically overwrite changes in `master` branch.

I looked around there are multiple options but I don't want to take chances with merging.

Comment: `git push -f origin master`

Comment: @MDXF: May be I am wrong but shouldn't I be using `-f` option with `merge` command and not with `push` command

Comment: You could try both and see what works for you

Comment: See below link for a solution of force overwrite: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42454737/984471

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies

Comment: it seems bit sketchy how easily (especially new programmers) can pull up this answer, and not fully understand the implications of using -f flag and cause problems. Even tho there is vvery good answer below

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Not really related to this answer, but I'd ditch `git pull`, which just runs `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  You are doing three merges, which is going to make your Git run three fetch operations, when one fetch is all you will need.  Hence:

```
git fetch origin   # update all our origin/* remote-tracking branches

git checkout demo         # if needed -- your example assumes you're on it
git merge origin/demo     # if needed -- see below

git checkout master
git merge origin/master

git merge -X theirs demo   # but see below

git push origin master     # again, see below
```

#### Controlling the trickiest merge

The most interesting part here is `git merge -X theirs`.  As [root545 noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40517464/1256452), the `-X` options are passed on to the merge strategy, and both the default `recursive` strategy and the alternative `resolve` strategy take `-X ours` or `-X theirs` (one or the other, but not both).  To understand what they do, though, you need to know how Git finds, and treats, *merge conflicts*.

A merge conflict can occur within some file<sup>1</sup> when the *base* version differs from both the *current* (also called local, HEAD, or `--ours`) version *and* the other (also called remote or `--theirs`) version of that same file.  That is, the merge has identified three revisions (three commits): base, ours, and theirs.  The "base" version is from the *merge base* between our commit and their commit, as found in the commit graph (for much more on this, see other StackOverflow postings).  Git has then found two sets of changes: "what we did" and "what they did".  These changes are (in general) found on a line-by-line, *purely textual* basis.  Git has no real understanding of file contents; it is merely comparing each line of text.

These changes are what you see in `git diff` output, and as always, they have *context* as well.  It's possible that things we changed are on different lines from things they changed, so that the changes seem like they would not collide, but the context has also changed (e.g., due to our change being close to the top or bottom of the file, so that the file runs out in our version, but in theirs, they have also added more text at the top or bottom).

If the changes happen on *different* lines—for instance, we change `color` to `colour` on line 17 and they change `fred` to `barney` on line 71—then there is no conflict: Git simply takes *both* changes.  If the changes happen on the same lines, but are *identical* changes, Git takes *one copy* of the change.  Only if the changes are on the same lines, but are different changes, or that special case of interfering context, do you get a modify/modify conflict.

The `-X ours` and `-X theirs` options tell Git how to resolve this conflict, by picking just one of the two changes: ours, or theirs.  Since you said you are merging `demo` (theirs) into `master` (ours) and want the changes from `demo`, you would want `-X theirs`.

Blindly applying `-X`, however, is dangerous.  Just because our changes did not conflict on a line-by-line basis does not mean our changes do not actually conflict!  One classic example occurs in languages with variable declarations.  The base version might declare an unused variable:

```
int i;
```

In our version, we delete the unused variable to make a compiler warning go away—and in *their* version, they add a loop some lines later, using `i` as the loop counter.  If we combine the two changes, the resulting code no longer compiles.  The `-X` option is no help here since the changes are on *different lines*.

If you have an automated test suite, the most important thing to do is to run the tests after merging.  You can do this after committing, and fix things up later if needed; or you can do it *before* committing, by adding `--no-commit` to the `git merge` command.  We'll leave the details for all of this to other postings.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can also get conflicts with respect to "file-wide" operations, e.g., perhaps we fix the spelling of a word in a file (so that we have a change), and they *delete* the entire file (so that they have a delete).  Git will not resolve these conflicts on its own, regardless of `-X` arguments.

---

#### Doing fewer merges and/or smarter merges and/or using rebase

There are three merges in both of our command sequences.  The first is to bring `origin/demo` into the local `demo` (yours uses `git pull` which, if your Git is very old, will fail to update `origin/demo` but will produce the same end result).  The second is to bring `origin/master` into `master`.

It's not clear to me who is updating `demo` and/or `master`.  If you write your own code on your own `demo` branch, *and* others are writing code and pushing it to the `demo` branch on `origin`, then this first-step merge can have conflicts, or produce a real merge.  More often than not, it's better to use rebase, rather than merge, to combine work (admittedly, this is a matter of taste and opinion).  If so, you might want to use `git rebase` instead.  On the other hand, if you never do any of your own commits on `demo`, you don't even *need* a `demo` branch.  Alternatively, if you want to automate a lot of this, but be able to check carefully when there are commits that both you and others, made, you might want to use `git merge --ff-only origin/demo`: this will fast-forward your `demo` to match the updated `origin/demo` if possible, and simply outright fail if not (at which point you can inspect the two sets of changes, and choose a real merge or a rebase as appropriate).

This same logic applies to `master`, although you are doing the merge *on* `master`, so you definitely do need a `master`.  It is, however, even likelier that you would want the merge to fail if it cannot be done as a fast-forward non-merge, so this probably also should be `git merge --ff-only origin/master`.

Let's say that you never do your own commits on `demo`.  In this case we can ditch the name `demo` entirely:

```
git fetch origin   # update origin/*

git checkout master
git merge --ff-only origin/master || die "cannot fast-forward our master"

git merge -X theirs origin/demo || die "complex merge conflict"

git push origin master
```

If you *are* doing your own `demo` branch commits, this is not helpful; you might as well keep the existing merge (but maybe add `--ff-only` depending on what behavior you want), or switch it to doing a rebase.  Note that all three methods may fail: merge may fail with a conflict, merge with `--ff-only` may not be able to fast-forward, and rebase may fail with a conflict (rebase works by, in essence, *cherry-picking* commits, which uses the merge machinery and hence can get a merge conflict).

Answer (score 89):

I had a similar issue, where I needed to effectively replace any file that had changes / conflicts with a different branch.

The solution I found was to use `git merge -s ours branch`.

Note that the option is `-s` and not `-X`. `-s` denotes the use of `ours` as a top level merge strategy, `-X` would be applying the `ours` option to the `recursive` merge strategy, which is not what I (or we) want in this case.

Steps, where `oldbranch` is the branch you want to overwrite with `newbranch`.

- `git checkout newbranch` checks out the branch you want to keep
- `git merge -s ours oldbranch` merges in the old branch, but keeps all of our files.
- `git checkout oldbranch` checks out the branch that you want to overwrite
- `get merge newbranch` merges in the new branch, overwriting the old branch

Comment: It didn't work for me. It solved the conflict(solved the conflicted files) but the file is not merged. And can't merge neither.

Comment: If anyone happens to get stuck where you are prompted to "Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary": Enter your message, then press the ESC key on your keyboard, type :wq and press ENTER to exit the prompt.

Answer (score 68):

This merge approach will add one commit on top of `master` which pastes in whatever is in `feature`, without complaining about conflicts or other crap.

[image]

## Before you touch anything

```sh
git stash
git status # if anything shows up here, move it to your desktop
```

## Now prepare master

```sh
git checkout master
git pull # if there is a problem in this step, it is outside the scope of this answer
```

## Get `feature` all dressed up

```sh
git checkout feature
git merge --strategy=ours master
```

## Go for the kill

```sh
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature
```

Comment: git push to finish

Comment: git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-ours . It worked when the commits were not cleanly merging. But this approach will not work always, to quote the source ```Changes from the other tree that do not conflict with our side are reflected in the merge result```. It did not work for me, as I had cleanly merging commits in my branch which was being overwritten. Is there any other way?

Comment: This did the trick for me! Exactly what I was looking for. (We had tried switching frameworks and it was a flop. We needed to cherry pick some recent work from on top of the bad framework, and then overwrite whatever was on master with our cherry-picked branch.)

Answer (score 50):

### These commands will help in overwriting code of `demo` branch into `master`

```
git fetch --all
```

#### Pull Your `demo` branch on local

```
git pull origin demo
```

#### Now checkout to `master` branch. This branch will be completely changed with the code on `demo` branch

```
git checkout master
```

#### Stay in the `master` branch and run this command.

```
git reset --hard origin/demo
```

`reset` means you will be resetting current branch

`--hard` is a flag that means it will be reset without raising any merge conflict

`origin/demo` will be the branch that will be considered to be the code that will forcefully overwrite current `master` branch

The output of the above command will show you your last commit message on `origin/demo` or `demo` branch
[image]

Then, in the end, force push the code on the `master` branch to your remote repo.

```
git push --force
```

Comment: Why was remote 'origin/demo' branch was used and not local 'demo' branch.

Comment: @NevetsKuro You can use local too.  
Both "git reset --hard demo" and "git reset --hard origin/demo" would result in the same action if the latest commits are git fetched using "git fetch --all" and pulled branch "demo".

Comment: It worked perfectly for my case

Answer (score 19):

You can try "ours" option in git merge,

> git merge branch -X ours
>
> This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring our version. Changes from the other tree that do not conflict
>                  with our side are reflected to the merge result. For a binary file, the entire contents are taken from our side.

Comment: This would be backwards, as the OP said he wants the `demo` version to be preferred even though he is merging into `master`.  There is `-X theirs` as well, but it's not clear that this is what the OP really wants.

Comment: You have not read the whole way. Your note describes what `ours` does when using on the backend with the `-s` option. When using `ours` with `-X`: _It discards everything the other tree did, declaring our history contains all that happened in it._

[source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-ours)

Answer (score 7):

When I tried using `-X theirs` and other related command switches I kept getting a merge commit. I probably wasn't understanding it correctly. One easy to understand alternative is just to delete the branch then track it again.

```
git branch -D <branch-name>
git branch --track <branch-name> origin/<branch-name>
```

This isn't exactly a "merge", but this is what I was looking for when I came across this question. In my case I wanted to pull changes from a remote branch that were force pushed.

You can do this without deleting your own branch too which is nice, use `git reset`:

```
git reset --hard origin/<branch-name>
```

Another SO post goes in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17336942/9990099).

Answer (score -1):

```
git checkout master
git merge demo
cd /root/of/source/
git checkout --theirs . # this will overwrite everything by img of demo
git add .
git commit -m "bla bla"
```