# Replace branch completely with another branch

Tags: git

I have 3 branches: `development`, `qa`, and `staging`. I have almost the same code in both `development` and `qa`, so making a pr from `development` to `qa` doesn't yield too many changes (and or conflicts).

But now I have a move all the stuff from `qa` to `staging`. And `qa` code is practically completely different and new from `staging`, so what's the best option? I searched and found this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624383/9664):

```
git checkout qa
git merge -s ours staging
git checkout staging
git merge qa
```

Is this a good idea for my case? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I don't want to lose all the commits from staging branch.

Comment: As qa and staging contains different code changes, you might get conflicts. So you need to resolve and merge them

Comment: yeah, what I want to do is replace all the code in staging with the code in qa, and don't want to solve conflicts, just replace the code as if you manually go file by file changing the code from the files in qa branch

Comment: you can use git merge with force overwrite, you can see this link for similar steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517129/git-merge-with-force-overwrite

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Please provide a concrete example of commits, current state and what you want in the end. You can also just try the commands and see what happens. Nothing is lost with Git.

Comment: It's should all be a big cycle: `development` branches off `master`; `development` is merged into `qa`; `qa` is merged into `staging`, and `staging` is merged into `master`. The only difference between the merges is the level of testing needed to achieve the desired confidence that you are ready for the  merge.

Comment: Yes, using `merge -s ours` is your best option here. You will end up with the snapshot of one branch only but keep the history of both. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4624357/112968 for a possible duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I 'overwrite', rather than 'merge', a branch on another branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624357/how-do-i-overwrite-rather-than-merge-a-branch-on-another-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to "completely replace", I'll go with `git reset`:

```
git checkout staging
git reset origin/qa --hard
```

This will make `staging` have the exact same content as `qa` *but* this will "erase" commits that may have been done on `staging` (the commits won't be deleted yet but they won't be visible in the history of `staging` anymore).

Comment: Is there any way to do this exact thing but without losing the staging commits?

Comment: _without losing the commits_ you mean see them in history but still overwrite all files with content from `qa`?

Answer (score 1):

[Gaël J's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389127/ga%c3%abl-j) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67976470/112968) is good, but there is a shorter (i.e. single) command, which doesn't require you to switch branches and doesn't interfere with your current working tree:

```
git branch -f staging origin/qa
```

If the branch is already shared with others (= pushed), you have to force-push to the remote repository and inform others that they have to rebase any existing work based on this branch.

If you want to put all staging commits on top of the remote-tracking branch `origin/qa`, use `rebase`:

```
git rebase origin/qa staging
```

Or, if you want to replace the content of tree referenced by `staging`, but still keep its old history, use the merge strategy `-s ours`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624383/112968) on ["How do I 'overwrite', rather than 'merge', a branch on another branch in Git?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4624357/112968)

Answer (score 1):

This question's answers answer something slightly different than I was looking for. Based on @knittl's answer, I tried to literally replace my main branch with the history of another branch, **without keeping any then-infant commits from the main branch**. Just literally, use one branch in place of the other.

I did this using the following trick:

```bash
git checkout branchB
git branch -mf main
git push --force -u origin main
```

This left my `main` branch with the *exact* same history as my `branchB`, so I literally removed everything that ever happened in `main`, and replaced it with what happened in `branchB`