# How to fetch only specific files on git

Tags: git, diff, fetch, pull

I want to save bandwidth and make my fetch/pull run faster, so i want to only update specific files and leave the rest unchanged, i don't care about their status in the project as they don't affect me. So how can i do so? first i want to check for all updated files between my local workspace and between the server/remote repository then choose some files from these to update... I've been looking around a lot and couldn't find something clean that works. I am new to git, i am used to TFS and SVN so try to explain.

Comment: I dont think this is possible in GIT. When you checkout a branch you are checking out a copy of that entire branch

Comment: Although... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/checkout-only-one-file-from-git

Comment: Git is snapshot-oriented, not file-oriented. If you want to checkout a file as it appears in a given commit, you need to get that entire commit (and its ancestry).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with git. Git requires you to do a complete check-in of the entire tree.

The closest thing you have in git is a shallow clone. That's a clone where you only get the latest files (for the entire tree), and cannot push to other repos.

Comment: but that would still waste time on downloading files that i don't need, isn't there a way to exclude/ignore such files from the pull/checkout?

Comment: As i said, this is not possible with git.