How to get a plain copy of a Git repository?
How do I clone (copy) a Git repository, so that the result isn't a Git repository, but an untracked copy (no .git directories)?
I have a repository on GitHub and I would like to know what options/flags to download the file so that they're on my local machine and are not a repository (no .git directories). Just the files - no VCS data.
I tried using the --bare flag, but didn't seem to work.

A directory that doesn't have .git subdirectory is not a GIt repository and cannot be cloned using git. Try to copy the directory and run git init in it. In case of problems [edit] the question, copy/paste the commands and output from the terminal and format as [code block].

Yes, I understand that. I have a repository on GitHub and I would like to know what options/flags to download the file so that they're on my local machine and are NOT a repository (no .git directories). Just the file - no VCS data

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779969/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/32260024/7976758 curl (or wget) https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<project>/<branch>/<file> Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+one+file

Just do a clone (with depth = 1) and then delete the .git folder!?

I think in my first edit I made the title of the question into the opposite of what you are trying to do (this is how I interpreted the body of the question). I made another edit that reverts the title and hopefully makes the intent clearer.

There's a 'download zip' option in the same dropdown from where the git clone URL is copied. This should help.


Get any branch or tag content as an archive and unpack that, e.g.
curl -sL https://github.com/github/codeql/archive/refs/heads/main.tar.gz \
| tar xzf -


But that is specific to the commercial service "github", and has little to do with "git" open source protocol and program, isn't it? I don't think that (outside what was said it comment: "clone and then remove .git directory") that there can be a solution in git. So I believe this kind of solution indeed (rely on specific access the server — that in addition to be a git repo host, also host other webservices on the same data —  has to offer to get the content of the repo). So I think this answer is as good as it gets. Yet, strictly speaking, the question is a git question

@chrslg I was answering for the specific case OP asked about: "I have a repository on GitHub and I would like to know what options/flags to download the file so that they're on my local machine and are not a repository (no .git directories). Just the files - no VCS data.".

@chrslg The Git solution without Github is git archive. It can even download a zip file from a remote repository if the remote permits it.

@j6t Interesting. That deserve an answer, I think. Because, I am not criticizing github based answer. I totally agree that OP wanted, in practice, a github answer. Yet, the question is tagged git, and, theoretically asked for a git answer. And too much people confuse git with non-git functionalities of specific commercial services such as github or gitlab.

@chrslg There are many answers like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32731709/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+one+file

A directory that doesn't have a .git directory in it (or Git repository metadata stored somewhere else) isn't a Git repository, and thus cannot be cloned. It's just a directory.
However, just like any directory, it can be copied.

Wrong answer (though I must admit the question is hard to understand). The OP asks: "how to clone a repository from GitHub without local directory being a clone?" Two other answers are more suitable.

The question was edited by a third-party to ask the opposite of what it originally asked, after I wrote my answer. My answer answers the question as stated by the OP at the time the answer was posted.

My advice is to rewrite the answer to address the real question, not the original confusing text.

Sorry, that was me. I originally made an edit that supports this answer but later realized that it was probably wrong.
