# How to download a single raw file using a deploy key from GitHub?

Tags: git, github, github-api, ssh-keys

I use a deploy key to clone a private git project on GitHub. I don't have a username and password to access the repo.

I want to know, how could I download just one file from the repo, without cloning the whole project?

The GitHub API to download a raw file seems to only support HTTP.

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-checkout-only-one-file-from-git-repository-sparse-checkout

Comment: I tried. But it hangs when I use the command.

Comment: is the file locked by someone else ??can you clone the repo ??

Comment: Yes. I can clone it.

Comment: Is the file present it the clone ??