# I need to checkout single folder of a tag from Bitbucket Git repo

Tags: git

I need to checkout single folder of a tag from Bitbucket Git repo. I have checked out the single folder of a branch from the Bitbucket by using the following steps:

```
mkdir <repo>
cd <repo>
git init
git remote add -f origin <url>
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo "some/dir/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "another/sub/tree" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

Like this can we checkout the single folder of a tag?

Comment: Update your command using the ` command would be more clear.

Comment: Doesn't `git checkout <TAG>` work? (where `<TAG>` is your tag)

Comment: yes, but i need to checkout one particular folder in tag. Is that possible??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to checkout only one file from git repository ('sparse checkout')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-checkout-only-one-file-from-git-repository-sparse-checkout)

Comment: Why are you initializing a new repo? Why don't you just cone it from your Bitbucket server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, *shallow* clone the repo, detach the HEAD at the tag, but do not check out anything:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch <tag> --no-checkout <url/repo.git>
cd repo
```

Next, checkout the folder:

```
git checkout HEAD -- <path>
```

---

The option `--branch` might be misleading here, but it works also with tags. From the git-clone(1) Manual Page:

> `--branch` can also take tags and detaches the HEAD at that commit in the resulting repository.

Comment: For example this is tag "clipper-release-18.1" we have 4 folders under tag i.e : bnw , bnw-clipper-db , bnw-clipper-jboss , bnw-clipper-workflows. So now i need to checkout one folder ( bnw-clipper-db)from bitbucket.Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: @sailakshmiAddala It is unclear what you are asking. Are the folders in the same repo? Have you cloned the repo already?

Comment: yes, folders are in the same repo. No i have not cloned the repo.