# How to get source code from git repo using DockerFile

Tags: linux, git, docker

I have Git and Docker on a remote Linux machine. The source code of my project is in a bare repo. I need a way of making the source code from this repo available to Docker during the build process.

Below is what I have now (which is basically the default template in VS 2017 for a Docker ASP.NET Core project).

Q: How do I make the code from a bare repo available? Is clone the best option here? My attempts probably fail because of auth-issues but since the repo is on the same machine I assume it should be possible to access it straight away without using ssh in this case? Can I make this path visible/accessible to the Docker process somehow?

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

RUN git clone ssh://user@gitserver/volume1/git/project // fails

RUN git clone /volume1/git/project // fails

COPY Test.sln ./
COPY Test/Test.csproj Test/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Test
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: repository '/volume1/git/project' does not exist

Comment: You are looking for a "volume mount": https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/. Basically, you tell docker and your os to make the directory containing the source from your local disk visible inside the container. Then use the files from that directory. But watch out, that means the container will not work on other machines that do not have the volume mount. Can you access the git repo from a server without authentication?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but what I have read is that volumes can't be used during an image build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Git repository outside the Docker build process; ideally, put the `Dockerfile` in the root directory of the repository itself.  `COPY` the contents of the repository into the image.

There are two big problems with trying to do `git clone` inside a Dockerfile:

1. If you have a private repository (which you often do) you need to get the credentials into Docker space to do the clone, and once you do, it's trivial for anyone to get them back out via `docker history` or `docker run`.
2. `docker build` will remember that it's already run a step in a previous build cycle, and so it won't want to repeat the `git clone` step, even if the upstream repository has changed.

It's also helpful for occasional testing to be able to build an image out of something that's not checked in (yet) and having the `git clone` hard-coded in the Dockerfile keeps you from ever being able to do that.

Comment: for point 1, just for everyones information, its possible to add the creds using git token. to remove the step that embeds the token in execution, one can squash the layers via "docker --squash" during build. note that this is experimental. and i agree with David that this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you expose the git repository. If you run gitweb you can run an http request to a raw version of the file you want to have. If you want to get only the latest file, you could do a shallow clone (depth=1) to fetch only the version you're interested in and copy the file from there. But you'll copy everything. So if the bare git repository you may use git show and pipe it to file.

```
git --no-pager --git-dir /path/to/bar/repo.git show branch:path/to/file >file
```

as found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467629/2955337

You would still need to have access to the host from the build container, so that can be tricky, I would script around it to first copy the file and then COPY the file. But personally I do a curl to GITWEB to fetch the file anonymously.

Answer (score 0):

With [BuildKit 0.11.0](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/releases/tag/v0.11.0) (Jan. 2023), you now have a new option to use in your Dockerfile.
Builtin [Dockerfile frontend has been updated to v1.5.0](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/releases/tag/dockerfile%2F1.5.0) and it includes:

> ### [dockerfile (labs): implement `ADD <git ref>` #2799](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/2799)
>
> e.g.,
>
> ```yaml
> # syntax=docker/dockerfile-upstream:master-labs
> # ↑ Will be included in `syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.5-labs`
> FROM alpine
> ADD --keep-git-dir=true https://github.com/moby/buildkit.git#v0.10.1 /buildkit
> ```

In your case:

```
ADD --keep-git-dir=true ssh://user@gitserver/volume1/git/project /project
```