# Force docker to rebuild a layer based on latest commit of a git repo

Tags: git, docker

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install mariadb-common mariadb-server mariadb-client nodejs npm -y
RUN git clone https://github.com/yigalirani/sqlrabbit.js.git && cd sqlrabbit.js && npm install
```

Note that the last line clones a git repo.

My question is: when calling `docker build .` , is there a way to force docker to check the latest commit of the git repo and rebuild the layer if needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was discussed in [this thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/best-practices-for-getting-code-into-a-container-git-clone-vs-copy-vs-data-container/4077/14) (git clone vs.copy) and this [blog post](https://firepress.org/en/best-practices-for-getting-code-into-a-container/) (using `wget`)

But to avoid [`git clone` caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39278224/6309), you will need to `ADD` a file whose content will change when a new commit is done.

[anq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243335/anq) suggests:

```
ADD https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPO/git/refs/heads/$BRANCH version.json
```

That uses the [GitHub refs API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-a-reference).

Comment: yes, that seems to solve the problem, but it  look like a hack. it would be nice of the docker folks to solve it more elegantly. how about a new 'GIT' instruction in the dockerfile?

Comment: @yigal It is not an hack, but a cache-busting technique common in Dockerfile. A Git instruction would be a local command which would need to come *after* the git clone, so too late. The GitHub API call can be done *before* the clone.

Comment: yes, I understand and will use it in my project. it would be nice  though if the docker system would do it automatically. instead of doing `RUN git clone <repo_name>` do a `GIT <repo name>`. basically I am suggesting a new instruction that is like 'add' and 'copy' but for git repos

Comment: @yigal That is a good idea! I am not sure though the Dockerfile syntax accepts new commands. It seems kind of frozen in term of API/commands, which might be a good thing.

Comment: only works for github though.. right?

Comment: @Duane True, this is using the GitHub API and would not work for another Git repositories hosting service. Note that the recent BuildKit (0.11.0) and Dockerfile 1.5.0 allow to copy/clone a repository (without the history) or just a file of a repository, with the [new `ADD git-ref` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75101766/6309). And that is *not* limited to GitHub.