# How to get a list of git submodules of repository before `git clone`?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to get a submodule list of a repo before preforming clone.

And then to  choose which submodule repo to clone.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: "git submodule init"
"git submodule update"

Comment: Do you want to clone submodules with or without cloning the superproject?

Comment: Yes, but I want to know the list of submodules without cloning the parent repository

Comment: Not generally, no.  But if the parent repository is hosted in a hosting provider like GitHub, Bitbucket, Azure Repos, etc then you could use their API to download the gitmodules file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to review the list of submodules of the first level without cloning the superproject download file `.gitmodules` from the superproject. You can use [`git archive`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467629/7976758):

```
git archive --format=tar --remote=$ORIGIN_URL HEAD -- .gitmodules | tar -O -xf -
```

As submodules could be recursive you have to repeat this for every submodule found in the downloaded `.gitmodules`.

After that you can clone any submodule's repository manually.

You may also want to review the list of submodules after cloning the superproject. First, clone without submodules:

```
git clone $ORIGIN_URL # Don't use `--recursive`
cd <repo_dir>
git submodule init
cat .gitmodules
git submodule update submodule1 submodule2…
```

Comment: So, I understand that there's no way doing this in one git command without downloading .gitmodules with third app?

Comment: For non-recursive submodules the first command (`git archive`) could be considered *one command*. But not for recursive submodules.