# Maven settings.xml duplication in GitLab

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have multi module Maven project. Each module has its own Git repo.

According to GitLab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/artifactory_and_gitlab/) each module must have `.m2/settings.xml` file for CI/CD via `.gitlab-ci.yml` to work.

I would like to avoid having same `.m2/settings.xml` file in each module.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several ways for achieving this

- **Hosting the settings.xml on a webserver**
  You could simply serve the settings.xml via a web server and `wget` it during your CI/CD process.
- **Clone the file via GIT**
  You can, as you already suggested, clone the file from one of the submodule repositories. There are ways for only retrieving parts of a repository, as discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-sparsely-checkout-only-one-single-file-from-a-git-repository)
- **Using a custom docker container with the correct Maven configuration**
  You could create your own docker container image to use during your CI/CD process. This image could use the current image as base image (i.e. via Docker's `FROM` instruction) and add your own custom settings.xml directly to the .m2 directory. Or to any directory you want.
  This would likely be the most elegant solution, however also the one that requires the most setup work. See [this resource](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry) for how to use docker images from private container registries during GitLab CI/CD.
- **Obviously, you could also just copy the file to each of the repositories**

Comment: I like the idea about docker image!

Answer (score 19):

The most convenient solution I figured out for my Maven projects on GitLab is using  [GitLab Custom environment variables of type File](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#custom-environment-variables-of-type-file) introduced with GitLab 11.11.

If you store the maven `settings.xml` content into a GitLab environment variable e.g. named `MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML` and set the type to `File`, the settings will be available as file named `$MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML` within each build job having access to this environment.

The maven build can pointed to this settings by either using the the param `-s` (e.g `mvn clean install -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML` or by copying the settings to the default location via `cp $MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML ~/.m2/settings.xml` before executing maven.
I'm doing the latter for now as maven sometimes struggles with the settings path.

By defining this environment variable in a [GitLab Group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/) above all maven projects, the same settings will be available to all maven projects as well.

Comment: This works fantastically and the same type of thing works as a regular variable for the MAVEN_OPTS.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the settings.xml as parameter of the build.

```
mvn clean install --settings path/to/your/settings.xml
```

Comment: I thought about it, but I think each gitlab repo doesnt have access to another repos. But this gives me idea - i can checkout settings.xml from another repo instead of copying it.