# Running "git archive" in Azure Git gives error message

Tags: git, azure, archive

I am trying to pull a single file from an Azure Git repo.

But if I run this:
`git archive --remote="ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/[organization]/[project]/[repo]" master myfile`

It returns an error:

```
remote: Could not find a Command Extension for Command:git-upload-archive
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This happens in both Linux and Windows.

On the other hand, note that these work fine:

`git clone "ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/[organization]/[project]/[repo]"`

`git ls-remote "ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/[organization]/[project]/[repo]"`

Comment: `git archive` relies on the archive-creating-program (`git-upload-archive`) being on the server. The other two rely on the Git-commit-sending-program (`git-upload-pack`) being on the server. Obviously this server only has the second program, not the first. (Probably it has the third program, `git-send-pack`, as well, to allow `git push`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to pull data from a file with this method:

`curl -u ":[Personal Access Token]" "https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/[project]/_apis/sourceProviders/TfsGit/filecontents?repository=[repo]&path=[filepath]&commitOrBranch=[branch]&api-version=5.0-preview.1"`

Answer (score 1):

Considering:

- the remote side (Azure) does not support git archive
- the git clone works

the obvious workaround becomes doing a [git clone --no-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54968394/6309), followed by a `git restore` of just the file you need.
Or a [sparse checkout](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html#filter-by-object-type):

```sh
git clone --filter=blob:none --sparse /url/repo
cd repo
git sparse-checkout init --cone

## or

git clone --filter=sparse:oid=shiny-app/.gitfilterspec` /url/repo
cd repo

# with .gitfilterspec including the file you need
```