# How to get old function from a file in old commit

Tags: git

let's say that i have file called getData as the following

```
class getData{
   public function retriveData() {
     echo 'data retrived';
   } 
   public function checkData() {
    echo 'data checked'
   }
}
```

then i edit it to be like this

```
class getData{                                                                                    
      public function retriveData() {
      echo 'data retrived';
     }                                          
}
```

then i commit the last change and after while i want to get checkData() back what is the best method to do that without damage any of my project files and make my file back to previous form

Comment: Do you know which commit had the old version? if so, `git checkout commitid` then copy it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sparsely checkout only one single file from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-sparsely-checkout-only-one-single-file-from-a-git-repository)

Comment: i used git revert to get missing lines thx guys

Answer (score 1):

You can "checkout" a file from a previous commit by runnning:

```
git checkout abc123 -- path/to/file/to/restore
```

Where `abc123` is the commit hash where the file was in the state you wanted it to be in.

You can also swap the commit ID with `HEAD~1` where the `1` represents the number of commits to go back from.

**Update;** As per @Roman Valeri, the newer, equivalent syntax would be:

```
git restore —source=abc123 — path/to/file
```

Comment: For completion, let's add the new alternative syntax `git restore --source=abc123 -- path/to/file`