# Obtain only a specific folder from a repository without cloning the entire repo

Tags: git

I've tried every way I can find online but I just can't make this work.  I have multiple repositories in Github which leverage actions.  And by multiple I mean pushing 1K (not mine actually, but long story).  I need to retrieve only the /.github folder and all of the files in it, I don't want the entire repository.  I need to scan the workflows and actions YAML files to get a sense of what these are actually doing, like building code, testing, building and testing, etc.  Could someone PLEASE help me with this, the sparse checkout just doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233327/is-it-possible-to-clone-only-part-of-a-git-project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sparsely checkout only one single file from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-sparsely-checkout-only-one-single-file-from-a-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269934/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467629/7976758

Comment: Those links didn't help a lot, they were pretty old and I'm not looking to check out just a specific file, I need an entire folder as I don't know what files will be there.  

This seems to work but it is waaaaay too slow:

    mkdir test
    cd test  
    git init  
    git remote add origin https://github.com/<myorg>/<myrepo>.git  
    git config core.sparseCheckout true  
    echo ".github" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout  
    git pull origin master  


The pull takes forever, is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't get my comment to put the commands I used on separate lines, even after following the formatting guide.

Comment: There is a new thing called a *partial clone*, but it's not ready for ordinary users. (As tricky as the sparse checkout stuff is, partial clone is considerably trickier, and requires sparse checkout too.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a partial "clone" of a repo, you can use sparse checkout:

```sh
# work folder
mkdir partialrepo
cd partialrepo

# new empty repo
git init

# point local repo at remote without cloning
git remote add origin https://pathtorepo

# enable sparse checkout
git config core.sparseCheckout true

# enumerate paths to check out
echo ".github" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

# and pull them
git pull origin whateverbranchyouwanttopull
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the echo statement does, I assume this is what tells it what is to be pulled?  I thought there was a "set" statement or something similar?

Comment: it outputs the string to the console, which is redirected to that file path - the sparse-checkout file is a list of paths covered.

Comment: Ah, okay gotcha.  So question, if I run it as is, just echoing .github to the file, does that mean ".github and anything else below"?  We'll need everything under .github, files, folders, subfolders, the works.

Comment: The -g option isn't working, git says it's an unknown option.  I'm using git 2.34.1.windows.1

Comment: And one last newbie question:  this command:

git pull origin master

Results in

`fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: I removed the -g. the script was fairly old, could have been deprecated, who knows - try the git remote add statement and the git pull statement again, please