# How do I get the size of sub directory from a directory in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems

Following is the code

```
import os
def get_size(path):
    total_size = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            fp = os.path.join(root, f)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return total_size

for root,dirs,files in os.walk('F:\House'):
   print(get_size(dirs))
```

OUTPUT :

```
F:\House 21791204366
F:\House\house md 1832264906
F:\House\house md\house M D 1 1101710538
F:\House\Season 2 3035002265
F:\House\Season 3 3024588888
F:\House\Season 4 2028970391
F:\House\Season 5 3063415301
F:\House\Season 6 2664657424
F:\House\Season 7 3322229429
F:\House\Season 8 2820075762
```

I need only sub directories after main directory with their sizes. My code is going till the last directory and writing its size.

As an example:

```
F:\House 21791204366
F:\House\house md 1832264906
F:\House\house md\house M D 1 1101710538
```

It has printed the size for `house md` as well as `house M D 1` (which is a subdirectory in `house md`). But I only want it till `house md` sub directory level.

DESIRED OUTPUT:
I need the size of each sub dir after the main dir level (specified by the user) and not sub sub dir (but their size should be included in parent dirs.)

How do I go about it ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. Your example output has `F:\House\house md\house M D 1` but then you say you don't want it. What is the desired output?

Comment: Desired output >> I want the size of each sub dir after the main dir level (specified by the user) and not sub sub dir (but their size should be included in parent dirs.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the size of each immediate subdirectory and the total size for the parent directory similar to `du -bcs */` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
"""Usage: du-bcs <parent-dir>"""
import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.exit(__doc__)  # print usage

parent_dir = sys.argv[1]
total = 0
for entry in os.scandir(parent_dir):
    if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False): # directory
        size = get_tree_size_scandir(entry)
        # print the size of each immediate subdirectory
        print(size, entry.name, sep='\t')  
    elif entry.is_file(follow_symlinks=False): # regular file
        size = entry.stat(follow_symlinks=False).st_size
    else:
        continue
    total += size
print(total, parent_dir, sep='\t') # print the total size for the parent dir
```

where [`get_tree_size_scandir()`[text in Russian, code in Python, C, C++, bash]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044).

The size of a directory here is the apparent size of all regular files in it and its subdirectories recursively. It doesn't count the size for the directory entries themselves or the actual disk usage for the files. Related: [why is the output of `du` often so different from `du -b`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5694741/4279).

Comment: get_tree_size_scandir() was enough for me. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `os.walk` in your `getpath` function, you can use `listdir` in conjunction with `isdir`:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if not os.path.isdir(file):
        # Do your stuff
        total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)

        ...
```

`os.walk` will visit the entire directory tree, whereas `listdir` will only visit the files in the current directory.

**However**, be aware that this will not add the size of the subdirectories to the directory size. So if "Season 1" has 5 files of 100MB each, and 5 directories of 100 MB each, then the size reported by your function will be 500MB only.

**Hint:** Use recursion if you want the size of subdirectories to get added as well.