# How to list the size of each file and directory and sort by descending size in Bash?

Tags: linux, file, bash

I found that there is no easy to get way the size of a directory in Bash?

I want that when I type `ls -<some options>`, it can list of all the sum of the file size of directory recursively and files at the same time and sort by size order.

Is that possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "size" of a directory?  The number of files under it (recursively or not)?  The sum of the sizes of the files under it (recursively or not)?  The disk size of the directory itself?  (A directory is implemented as a special file containing file names and other information.)

Comment: should be The sum of the sizes of the files under it recursively

Comment: @Kit: Then `du` is the answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson @KitHo `du` command estimates file space usage so you cannot use it if you want to get the exact size.

Comment: @ztank1013: Depending on what you mean by "the exact size", `du` (at least the GNU coreutils version) probably has an option to provide the information.

Comment: @KeithThompson By "the exact size" I mean the size in bytes of a file (or the sum of file sizes if we are talking about more files), which is probably the size @KitHo is talking about, isn't it?  
As an example try to `ls -l filename` and compare it with `du filename`.  
And please if such a option for `du` exists, I'd be more than curios to know it.

Comment: Yes. The sum of the file sizes

Comment: @KitHo What about my answer below? does it respond to your needs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ls to list directories and their total sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1019116/608639)

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Simply navigate to directory and run following command:

```
du -a --max-depth=1 | sort -n
```

OR add -h for human readable sizes and -r to print bigger directories/files first.

```
du -a -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr
```

Comment: `du -h` requires `sort -h` too, to ensure that, say `981M` sorts before `1.3G`; with `sort -n` only the numbers would be taken into account and they'd be the wrong way round.

Comment: This doesn't list the size of the individual files within the current directory, only the size of its subdirectories and the total size of the current directory.  How would you include individual files in the output as well (to answer OP's question)?

Comment: @ErikTrautman to list the files also you need to add `-a` and use `--all` instead of `--max-depth=1` like so `du -a -h --all | sort -h`

Comment: Awesome! I've been doing something lamer for a few years now. :)

Comment: `sort -h` only works on GNU's version / Linux, no luck with BSD / OS X.

Answer (score 34):

Apparently `--max-depth` option is not in Mac OS X's version of the `du` command. You can use the following instead.

`du -h -d 1 | sort -n`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not show the files, but only the folder sizes. `-a` does not work with `-d` either.

Comment: To show files and folders, I combined 2 commands: `l -hp | grep -v / && du -h -d 1`, which shows the normal file size from `ls` for files, but uses `du` for directories.

Comment: The following has worked for me on Mac: `du -h -d 0 * | sort -hr`

Answer (score 26):

```
du -s -- * | sort -n
```

(this willnot show hidden (.dotfiles) files)

Use `du -sm` for Mb units etc. I always use

```
du -smc -- * | sort -n
```

because the total line (`-c`) will end up at the bottom for obvious reasons :)

#### PS:

- See comments for handling dotfiles
- I frequently use e.g. 'du -smc /home/*/* | sort -n |tail' to get a feel of where exactly the large bits are sitting

Comment: `du --max-depth=1|sort -n` or `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1|xargs du -s|sort -n` for including dotfiles too.

Comment: @arnoud: I use that too, but it didn't seem the right addition for this question (/answer) :)

Comment: @arnaud576875 `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 du -s | sort -n` if some of the found paths could contain spaces.

Comment: This is a great variant to get a human readable view of the biggest: `sudo du -smch * | sort -h | tail`

Answer (score 23):

### Command

```
du -h --max-depth=0 * | sort -hr
```

### Output

```
3,5M    asdf.6000.gz
3,4M    asdf.4000.gz
3,2M    asdf.2000.gz
2,5M    xyz.PT.gz
136K    xyz.6000.gz
116K    xyz.6000p.gz
88K test.4000.gz
76K test.4000p.gz
44K test.2000.gz
8,0K    desc.common.tcl
8,0K    wer.2000p.gz
8,0K    wer.2000.gz
4,0K    ttree.3
```

### Explanation

- `du` displays "disk usage"
- `h` is for "human readable" (both, in sort and in du)
- `max-depth=0` means `du` will not show sizes of subfolders (remove that if you want to show all sizes of every file in every sub-, subsub-, ..., folder)
- `r` is for "reverse" (biggest file first)

### ncdu

When I came to this question, I wanted to clean up my file system. The command line tool `ncdu` is way better suited to this task.

Installation on Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ncdu
```

Usage:

Just type `ncdu [path]` in the command line. After a few seconds for analyzing the path, you will see something like this:

```
$ ncdu 1.11 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help
--- / ---------------------------------------------------------
.  96,1 GiB [##########] /home
.  17,7 GiB [#         ] /usr
.   4,5 GiB [          ] /var
    1,1 GiB [          ] /lib
  732,1 MiB [          ] /opt
. 275,6 MiB [          ] /boot
  198,0 MiB [          ] /storage
. 153,5 MiB [          ] /run
.  16,6 MiB [          ] /etc
   13,5 MiB [          ] /bin
   11,3 MiB [          ] /sbin
.   8,8 MiB [          ] /tmp
.   2,2 MiB [          ] /dev
!  16,0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
    8,0 KiB [          ] /media
    8,0 KiB [          ] /snap
    4,0 KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4,0 KiB [          ] /srv
!   4,0 KiB [          ] /root
e   4,0 KiB [          ] /mnt
e   4,0 KiB [          ] /cdrom
.   0,0   B [          ] /proc
.   0,0   B [          ] /sys
@   0,0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0,0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0,0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0,0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
```

Delete the currently highlighted element with <kbd>d</kbd>, exit with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: You could also write du -hs * | sort -hr. 
-s (summarize) is same as --max-depth=0

Answer (score 6):

`ls -S` sorts by size. Then, to show the size too, `ls -lS` gives a long (`-l`), sorted by size (`-S`) display. I usually add `-h` too, to make things easier to read, so, `ls -lhS`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was not clear from your post. You want `du`, seems someone has posted it. @sehe: Depends on your definition of real — it is showing the amount of space the directory is using to store itself. (It's just not also adding in the size of the subentries.) It's not a random number, and it's not always 4KiB.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and fast:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | parallel du -s | sort -n
```

*requires [GNU Parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel).

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have figured out what you want to do.  This will give a sorted list of all the files and all the directories, sorted by file size and size of the content in the directories.

```
(find . -depth 1 -type f -exec ls -s {} \;; find . -depth 1 -type d -exec du -s {} \;) | sort -n
```

Comment: Nevermind, sehe has presented a much simpler solution.  I learn something new every day!

Comment: I don't think using `du` is an option, It will give you just an approximate result.

Answer (score 0):

*[enhanced version]*
This is going to be much faster and precise than the *initial version* below and will output the sum of all the file size of current directory:

```
echo `find . -type f -exec stat -c %s {} \; | tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/+$//g'` | bc
```

the `stat -c %s` command on a file will return its size in bytes. The `tr` command here is used to overcome `xargs` command limitations (apparently piping to `xargs` is splitting results on more lines, breaking the logic of my command). Hence `tr` is taking care of replacing line feed with `+` (plus) sign. `sed` has the only goal to remove the last `+` sign from the resulting string to avoid complains from the final `bc` (basic calculator) command that, as usual, does the math.

**Performances:** I tested it on several directories and over ~150.000 files top (the current number of files of my fedora 15 box) having what I believe it is an amazing result:

```
# time echo `find / -type f -exec stat -c %s {} \; | tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/+$//g'` | bc
12671767700

real    2m19.164s
user    0m2.039s
sys 0m14.850s
```

Just in case you want to make a comparison with the `du -sb /` command, it will output an estimated disk usage in bytes (`-b` option)

```
# du -sb /
12684646920 /
```

As I was expecting it is a little larger than my command calculation because the `du` utility returns allocated space of each file and not the actual consumed space.

*[initial version]*
You cannot use `du` command if you need to know the exact sum size of your folder because (as per man page citation) `du` estimates file space usage. Hence it will lead you to a wrong result, an approximation (maybe close to the sum size but most likely greater than the actual size you are looking for).

I think there might be different ways to answer your question but this is mine:

```
ls -l $(find . -type f | xargs) | cut -d" " -f5 | xargs | sed 's/\ /+/g'| bc
```

It finds all files under . directory (change . with whatever directory you like), also hidden files are included and (using `xargs`) outputs their names in a single line, then produces a detailed list using `ls -l`. This (sometimes) huge output is piped towards cut command and only the fifth field (`-f5`), which is the file size in bytes is taken and again piped against `xargs` which produces again a single line of sizes separated by blanks. Now take place a sed magic which replaces each blank space with a plus (`+`) sign and finally `bc` (basic calculator) does the math.

It might need additional tuning and you may have `ls` command complaining about arguments list too long.

Comment: if the diretory is too large, it hangs up for a long time, try to work on your home directory :p

Comment: @KitHo well, I am afraid there is no easy and fast way to get a precise result without searching every single file and adding its size, hence command laziness mainly depends on how many files are underneath the searched directory...   
But I believe there is margin for improvements... nice challenge!

Comment: @KitHo hey there, take a look at the _enhanced version_ in my answer... and let me know of course!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution.

```
$ for entry in $(ls); do du -s "$entry"; done | sort -n
```

the result will look like

```
2900    tmp
6781    boot
8428    bin
24932   lib64
34436   sbin
90084   var
106676  etc
125216  lib
3313136 usr
4828700 opt
```

changing "du -s" to "du -sh" will show human readable size, but we won't be able to sort in this method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below to list files by size
du -h | sort -hr | more
or
du -h --max-depth=0 * | sort -hr | more

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use du in a simple way.

```
du -sh */ | sort -n
```

This provides me with an idea of what directories are consuming the most space.  I can then run more precise searches later.

Comment: This kind of works, but ignores the units on the size of the file when sorting.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` `du -hsx 2>/dev/null * | sort -hr | less`

```
4.9G    var
2.2G    usr
61M     root
9.0M    etc
6.5M    home
824K    init
36K     run
16K     lost+found
4.0K    tmp
4.0K    srv
4.0K    opt
4.0K    mnt
4.0K    media
4.0K    boot
0       sys
0       sbin
0       proc
0       libx32
0       lib64
0       lib32
0       lib
0       dev
0       bin
(END)
```