# Fastest ways to get a directory Size and Size on disk

Tags: windows, linux, bash

I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463554/bash-how-can-i-list-out-the-size-of-each-file-and-directory-recursively-and-so/7465023#7465023) to a similar question but what I'd like to do now is to emulate using bash the Windows "Directory --> right click --> Properties" function (see fig.).

[image]

I was able to reproduce something like the **Size:** in bytes using this command:

```
echo $(find . -type f -printf "%s+") | sed 's/+$//g' | bc
```

which is quite fast but is it possible to get info faster (than find) or do the math faster (than bc)? 
In addition I would use the `du -sb` command to emulate the **Size on Disk:** and probably another couple of `find` to count files and directory and emulate the **Contains:** line.

Are there better ways to emulate such results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming cygwin:

```
cd /cygdrive/c

printf "Size: %s", $( du --apparent-size -sh )
printf "Size on disk: %s", $( du  -sh )
find . -printf "%y\n" | awk '
  $1 == "d" {dirs++} 
  END {printf("Contains: %d files, %d folders\n", NR-dirs, dirs)}
'
```

Comment: Liked a lot the use of `find` and `awk` to get files and directories count (+1 for it!) but I am not sure about the `--apparent-size` option. Is it what Windows returns? From the `du` man page I am not sure it is what I meant: the exact directory Size.

Comment: About files/directories count: symbolic links pointing to a directory? You will count them as files (always). Well maybe they are actually files anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a quick and dirty utility based on [nftw(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw).

The utility is basically just the manpage sample, with some stats added.

#### Functional

I opted to

- stay within a single mountpoint
- not follow symlinks (for simplicity *and* because it is usually what you want)
- note that it will still count the size of the *symlinks* themselves :)
- it shows apparent size (the length of a file) *as well as* the size on disk (allocated blocks).

#### Tests, speed

I tested the binary (/tmp/test) on my box:

```
# clear page, dentry and attribute caches
echo 3> /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
time /tmp/test /
```

output

```
Total size: 28433001733
In 878794 files and 87047 directories (73318 symlinks and 0 inaccessible directories)
Size on disk 59942192 * 512b = 30690402304

real    0m2.066s
user    0m0.140s
sys 0m1.910s
```

I haven't compared to your tooling, but it does seem rather quick. Perhaps you can take the source and build your own version for maximum speed?

To test whether **sparse files** were in fact correctly reported:

```
mkdir sparse
dd bs=1M seek=1024 count=0 of=sparse/file.raw
ls -l sparse/
./test sparse/
```

Output:

```
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 sehe sehe 1073741824 2011-09-23 22:59 file.raw

Total size: 1073741884
In 1 files and 1 directories (0 symlinks and 0 inaccessible directories)
Size on disk 0 * 512b = 0
```

#### Code

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uintmax_t total        = 0ul;
static uintmax_t files        = 0ul;
static uintmax_t directories  = 0ul;
static uintmax_t symlinks     = 0ul;
static uintmax_t inaccessible = 0ul;
static uintmax_t blocks512    = 0ul;

static int
display_info(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
             int tflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{
    switch(tflag)
    {
        case FTW_D:
        case FTW_DP:  directories++;  break;
        case FTW_NS:
        case FTW_SL:
        case FTW_SLN: symlinks++;     break;
        case FTW_DNR: inaccessible++; break;
        case FTW_F:   files++;        break;
    }
    total += sb->st_size;
    blocks512 += sb->st_blocks;
    return 0; /* To tell nftw() to continue */
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int flags = FTW_DEPTH | FTW_MOUNT | FTW_PHYS;

    if (nftw((argc < 2) ? "." : argv[1], display_info, 20, flags) == -1)
    {
        perror("nftw");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Total size: %7jd\n", total);
    printf("In %jd files and %jd directories (%jd symlinks and %jd inaccessible directories)\n", files, directories, symlinks, inaccessible);
    printf("Size on disk %jd * 512b = %jd\n", blocks512, blocks512<<9);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compile with...

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

Comment: If you put the static global counters in a namespace and mark them as "thread_local" then you can use your approach as a thread-safe way of getting the disk size information.