# Traversing a Filesystem with fts(3)

Tags: c, linux, unix, filesystems, traversal

I have a question on `fts(3)`.  I am getting a segmentation fault whenever I try to access any members of the `fts_children()` function.  When I read the man page at http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fts.3.html it claims to fill itself after the read function runs and returns a linked list linked through the `link` field in the structure.  My suspicion is that the child_function is returning nothing but I feel like that doesn't line up with the man page.  Am I supposed to be adding these files to the child buffer because I thought that was being done automatically?  My code is below,
Thanks!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fts.h>
#include<string.h>

int compare (const FTSENT**, const FTSENT**);

int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
{

        FTS* file_system = NULL;
        FTSENT* child = NULL;
        FTSENT* parent = NULL;
        FTSENT* temp = NULL;

        file_system = fts_open(argv + 1,FTS_COMFOLLOW | FTS_NOCHDIR,&compare);

        while( (parent = fts_read(file_system)) != NULL)
        {

             child = fts_children(file_system,0);
             printf("%s\n", child->fts_path);


        }
//      while (child ->fts_link != NULL)
      //         child = child->fts_link;
        fts_close(file_system);
        return 0;
}

int compare(const FTSENT** one, const FTSENT** two){
        return (strcmp((*one)->fts_name, (*two)->fts_name));
}
"test_fs.c" 43L, 1108C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add a NULL check.

You might want to

- add one for `file_system`
- check for command line arguments
- Add more errorhandling:

  > The `fts_children()` function returns a pointer to an `FTSENT` structure describing the first entry in a `NULL` terminated linked list of files in the directory, if successful. The `fts_children()` function may fail and set `errno` for any of the errors that the `chdir()`, `malloc()`, `opendir()`, `readdir()`, and `stat()` functions specify.

**Update** To the new question(s) in the comment:

- The while loop for linked list traversal was misplaced (outside the outer loop?)
- The printf displayed only the path... not the filename.

while you're at it:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fts.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>

int compare (const FTSENT**, const FTSENT**);

int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
{
    FTS* file_system = NULL;
    FTSENT* child = NULL;
    FTSENT* parent = NULL;

    if (argc<2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <path-spec>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(255);
    }

    file_system = fts_open(argv + 1,FTS_COMFOLLOW | FTS_NOCHDIR,&compare);

    if (NULL != file_system)
    {
        while( (parent = fts_read(file_system)) != NULL)
        {
            child = fts_children(file_system,0);

            if (errno != 0)
            {
                perror("fts_children");
            }

            while ((NULL != child)
                && (NULL != child->fts_link))
            {
                child = child->fts_link;
                printf("%s%s\n", child->fts_path, child->fts_name);
            }
        }
        fts_close(file_system);
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare(const FTSENT** one, const FTSENT** two)
{
    return (strcmp((*one)->fts_name, (*two)->fts_name));
}
```

Sample output fragment:

```
./.profiles/sehe/.opera/icons/cache/g_0000
./.profiles/sehe/.opera/icons/cache/g_0000/opr00002.tmp
./.profiles/sehe/.opera/icons/cache/g_0000/opr00003.tmp
./.profiles/sehe/home/sehe/.mozilla
fts_children: Permission denied
./.vbox-sehe-ipc/lock
```

Comment: Added proper `errno` handling there too.

Comment: thank you.  This was actually just a program to see if i knew how to use it clearly i did not.  What I don't understand is why the files don't print out, only the directories do and why can i not the traverse the linked list (the commented while loop)?

Comment: @tpar44 Erm, yeah I didn't pay it much attention because you didn't ask anything about it. I have **now fixed that part** of the code too (updated the answer)

Comment: Thank you so much! However, Can I ask one more thing of you? My aim wasn't to have someone else do the example for me, but rather learn how to use fts(3) as it looks like a a function I should know.  My question is, why did you move the second while loop inside of the first one? I thought that the function function returned a linked list for everything read, am I mistaken?

Comment: @tpar44 I moved it inside the while loop, since the fts_children call was also there... It kinda made sense to iterate once for _each_ result you get from `fts_read` instead of just the last.

Comment: @tpar For more info, [`man fts(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fts.3.html) looks to be a far finer source. FWIW: I vastly prefer the `*ftw` interfaces - which are callback based, see e.g. this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7672081/85371

Answer (score 9):

If you are only interested in traversing all directories and files for the specified path(s), just repeatedly call `fts_read`.

If you want to only iterate through the stream, @sehe's example could be rewritten as:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fts.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>

int compare (const FTSENT**, const FTSENT**);
void indent (int i);

int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
{
    FTS* file_system = NULL;
    FTSENT *node,    = NULL;

    if (argc<2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <path-spec>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(255);
    }

    file_system = fts_open(argv + 1,FTS_COMFOLLOW|FTS_NOCHDIR,&compare);

    if (NULL != file_system)
    {
        while( (node = fts_read(file_system)) != NULL)
        {
            switch (node->fts_info) 
            {
                case FTS_D :
                case FTS_F :
                case FTS_SL:
                    indent(node->fts_level);
                    printf("%s\n", node->fts_name);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        fts_close(file_system);
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare(const FTSENT** one, const FTSENT** two)
{
    return (strcmp((*one)->fts_name, (*two)->fts_name));
}

void indent(int i)
{
    for (; i > 0; i--) 
        printf("    ");
}
```

When you run it, it iterates through the stream and lists all files and directories in order:

```
★ mkdir -p test/A/1 test/A/2 test/B/1 test/B/2

★ tree test                                   
test
├── A
│   ├── 1
│   └── 2
└── B
    ├── 1
    └── 2

★ ./fts test                                  
test
    A
        1
        2
    B
        1
        2
```

Call `fts_children` only if you want a list of child nodes of a specific directory. In that case you must call `fts_read` at least once before calling `fts_children`; otherwise `fts_children` will only return nodes specified in `argv` parameter to `fts_open`.

Comment: Upvoting because man fts does not explicitly state that subsequently calling fts_read will walk the filesystem. It implies it, but it is not at all obvious.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to use fts in order to get the total number of regular files in root directory without traversing them first (which can take quite a while ...)

Comment: Guess not. You'll have to call `fts_read()` once, then `fts_children()` and iterate through the linked list it returns and check if each child is a regular file or something else.

Comment: The man page states `Either FTS_LOGICAL or FTS_PHYSICAL must be provided to the fts_open() function.`  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html

Comment: @ishmael, I believe `FTS_COMFOLLOW` implies `FTS_LOGICAL`, at least per the [source](https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/io/fts.c.html#898): `if (ISSET(FTS_LOGICAL) || follow) { ...`