# How to list directory size of all child directories?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

From the shell, I need to list the size of all child directories. I am currently using:

```
du -hs * | sort -hr
```

However, this only gets one level down and does not traverse the directory tree.

Comment: `du` displays the size of all directories in the tree by default.  The `-s` option stops it doing that.  What's wrong with `du -h . | sort -hr`?

Comment: [How to recursively find the amount stored in directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67806/56041), [Display each sub-directory size in a list format using one line command in Bash?](https://superuser.com/q/554319/173513), [Using ls to list directories and their total sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1019116/608639), [How to get the summarized sizes of directories and their subdirectories?](https://superuser.com/q/162749/173513), [How can I list out the size of each file and directory (recursively) and sort by size decendingly in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7463554/608639), etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest is:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 parent
```

This will show all sizes of the children of `parent` If you also want the grandchildren, you can do

```
du -h --max-depth=2 parent
```

If you want the whole family

```
du -h parent
```

All these will just summarize the total directory size of each subdirectory up to a given level (except the last, it will give for all)

If you don't want the content of the subdirectories, add the `-S` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `**/*`

```
shopt -s globstar
du -hs **/* | sort -hr
shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: This requires the `globstar` option to be enabled via `shopt -s globstar` before it will be usable.

Answer (score 1):

If sorting you will likely want a consistent output instead of having some in GB, some in MB, some in KB.... And if I read the OP correctly, it isn't getting the directory tree, and that's a *problem*, right?

It isn't listing subdirs because of the -s. Take that out (again, sorry if I'm misreading.)

```
du -b | sort -n
```

This lists all sizes in bytes, so you only need `-n` for `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are nice, but they'll also list FILES and not just directories.  The below will return the sizes of all directories and only the directories:

`find . -type d -exec du -sh {} \; | sort -hr`

Answer (score 0):

The `maxdepth` feature should solve your issue, but for some strange reason, it seems not to work:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec du -k {} \;
```

Maybe somebody can explain why the `maxdepth` is not taken into account?

Comment: Because you did not specify -s