# How to show file and folder size in ls format

Tags: linux, bash

ls -l will show all file and folder in detail information. but folder size is not correct(alwasy show 4.0k).

So how to show file/folder as `ls -l` format besides folder with correct size. Thanks!

ls -l format:

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 jerry jerry XXX.0K Mar  3 14:34 Flask-0.10.1  
-rw-rw-r--  1 jerry jerry 532K Mar  3 14:25 Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz  
drwxrwxr-x 10 jerry jerry XXXK Feb  8 15:41 leveldb1.15
```

Comment: Please show us an example of your `ls` listing.

Comment: you can use *awk* to sum the sizes.

Comment: if you only need file and folder size, why not run by `du -k *` directly?

Comment: A bit of semantics, directories don't really contain sizes on *nix based fs's, they just contain metadata and filenames. Anyway, if my answer doesn't do what you're looking for please update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-printf` option of `find` to get most of the info - see [the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) for more info. The easiest way I know to find the size of a directory including everything inside it is with `du -s`, so you will have to print/paste these values together. eg:

```
paste <(find . -maxdepth 1 -printf "%M %u %c %p\n") <(find . -maxdepth 1 -exec du -s {} \; | cut -f1 ) | column -t
```

Sample output:

```
drwxrwxr-x  ooh Thu  Apr  3  07:07:45  2014  .           12260
-rw-rw-r--  ooh  Thu  Apr  3  07:07:41  2014  ./test.txt  5080
drwxrwxr-x  ooh  Thu  Apr  3  07:07:54  2014  ./testdir   7140
```

So: permission/owner/date/name/size in bytes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are looking for - but from [`man ls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#ls-invocation):

> --block-size=SIZE scale sizes by SIZE before printing them.  E.g., '--block-size=M' prints sizes in units of 1,048,576  bytes. See SIZE
>   format below.
>
> SIZE  is  an integer and optional unit (example: 10M is 10*1024*1024).
>   Units are K, M, G, T, P, E, Z, Y (powers of 1024) or KB, MB, ...
>   (powers of 1000).

EDIT:
Based on your comment I would set up an alias to get an output which gives you the desired data but breaks the typical format of `ls` - e.g.:

```
alias lsd="ls -l && du -h --max-depth 1"
```

Result:

```
$ lsd
total 4
dr-xr-xr-x 4 user group 4096 Mar 12  2012 network
12K ./network
16K .
```

I do not know of any way to achieve your goal with `ls` only.

Comment: I mean ```ls``` will always show folder size with 4.0k which is not actually folder size.

Comment: I see - I guess you want to show `ls` the size of the contents a folder contains? So according to your example you expect the folder size to be 532K?

Comment: I expect show total size for folder in ls -l result. I do not expect only use ```ls```.

Comment: It will not get any better than that. What you get with an alias is easy to do. If you invest some work you could of course rebuild/mimic the format of the output on your own. By the way, your question has already been asked. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019116/using-ls-to-list-directories-and-their-total-sizes

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `ls`. But, You can try this,

```
ls -lhrt | awk '$1 ~ /^d/{"du -sh $9" | getline s; split(s,a," ");$5=a[1];}1'
```

Comment: Are you sure this works correctly? the size of the folders is always the same.

Comment: Same for me as well,  feels like it's getting the parent size and putting it on all the subdirs, though not sure why. Also won't work if dirnames have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

For sure there's a better way, but this works for me:

```
ls -l | while read f
do
 echo -ne $( echo $f | cut -f -4 -d ' ')
 echo -ne " $(du -s $(echo $f | cut -f 9 -d ' ') | cut -f 1) ";
 echo $( echo $f | cut -f 6- -d ' ');
done
```

Answer (score 0):

quoting @izx

> The directory is just a link to a list of files. So the size which you
>   are seeing is not the total space occupied by the folder but the space
>   occupied by the link. The minimum size a file or directory entry/link
>   must occupy is one block, which is usually 4096 bytes/4K on most
>   ext3/4 filesystems.

So the minimum size displayed can be only `4.0k`

Answer (score 0):

Made a script similar to this (replicating some `ls` options) before, made `du` change and should work here

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ ! -d "$1" ]] && echo "Error $1 not a directory" 1>&2 && exit

for f in "$1"/*; do
  f="${f##*/}"
  symlink=
  if [[ "$(stat -c '%h' "$f")" -gt 9 ]]; then
    string="$(stat -c "%A %h %U %G" "$f")"
  else
    string="$(stat -c "%A  %h %U %G" "$f")"
  fi

  t="$(stat -c "%x" "$f")"

  date="$(date -d "$t" "+%-d")"
  if [[ $date -lt 10 ]]; then
    date="$(date -d "$t" "+%b  %-d %H:%M")"
  else
    date="$(date -d "$t" "+%b %d %H:%M")"
  fi

  if [[ -h $f ]]; then
    size="$(ls -sh "$f" | cut -d ' ' -f1)"
    symlink="$f -> $(readlink "$f")"
    f=
  elif [[ -d $f ]]; then
    size="$(du -sh "$f" | cut -f1 2>&1)"
    f="$f/"
  elif [[ -f $f ]]; then
    size="$(ls -sh "$f" | cut -d ' ' -f1)"
  else
    echo "Error $f" 1>&2 && exit
  fi

  printf "%s %-4s %s %s\n" "$string" "$size" "$date" "${f}$symlink"
done
```

Will obviously be quite a bit slower than regular `ls`, since it has to calculate size.

Example output

```
> ./abovescript "./testdir"
drwxrwxr-x  5 owner group 11M  Apr  3 06:53 workspace/
-rwxrwxr-x  1 owner group 8.0K Mar 30 03:53 a.out
lrwxrwxrwx  1 owner group 0    Apr  3 07:19 foo -> test/file
```

Comment: To improve speed would probably re-write it to carefully loop over `du -sh *` (space, etc... issues), so it only calls `du` once. But not taking the time to do it now.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
du -b -d 1
```

This prints the disk usage for each folder to a depth of 1, which is the equivalent of ls -al

Comment: Hi mikea, it seems same effect as ```du -sh *```, it only show size and name, I need other information such as time, owner, rwx attribute as ```ls -l```