# List all directories sorted by size in descending order

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a requirement to sort all directories of current directory  in descended order by size.

I tried following

`du -sh * | sort -rg`

It is listing all the folders by size but it's just listing by size of folder by values. However it's not sorting correcting. 100 MB Dir should be listed before 200KB.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Try `-h` instead of `-g` in your `sort` command.

Comment: It didnt work for me in MAC. Getting following issue. du -sh * | sort -rh sort: invalid option -- h Try `sort --help' for more information.

Comment: That's odd, I tried it on mac and ubuntu before posting my comment.

Comment: yea.. not sure, but -h option is missing in sort --help

Comment: Which version of mac?

Comment: This can be of help too: https://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size

Comment: mac OS seirra 10.12

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ls to list directories and their total sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1019116/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to just go straight to comparing bytes.

```
du -b * | sort -nr
```

`du -b` reports bytes.

`sort -n` sorts numerically. Obviously, `-r` reverses.

My /tmp before I clean it -

```
104857600       wbxtra_RESIDENT_07202018_075931.wbt
815372  wbxtra_RESIDENT_07192018_075744.wbt
215310  Slack Crashes
148028  wbxtra_RESIDENT_07182018_162525.wbt
144496  wbxtra_RESIDENT_07182018_163507.wbt
141688  wbxtra_RESIDENT_07182018_161957.wbt
56617   Notification Cache
20480   ~DFFA6E4895E749B423.TMP
16384   ~DF543949D7B4DF074A.TMP
13254   AdobeARM.log
3614    PhishMeOutlookReporterLoader.log
3448    msohtmlclip1/01
3448    msohtmlclip1
512     ~DF92FFF2C02995D884.TMP
28      ExchangePerflog_8484fa311d504d0fdcd6c672.dat
0       WPDNSE
0       VPMECTMP
0       VBE
```

Comment: By the way, this is a great way to fairly quickly find your worst offenders on a full disk. Pipe it through a `head -50` and evaluate.

Answer (score 10):

`-g` is for floats. For human-readable output use human-readable sort:

```
du -sh * | sort -rh
```

If you have numfmt utility from coreutils, you can use numeric sort with numfmt formatting:

```
du -B 1 -s * | sort -rn | numfmt --to=iec -d$'\t' --field=1
```

Comment: It didnt work for me in MAC. Getting following issue.  du -sh * | sort -rh
sort: invalid option -- h
Try `sort --help' for more information.

Comment: Uch. Maybe try just numerical: `du -s * | sort -rn` ?

Comment: Yes it works partially. But it's not listing as MB and KB. It's not displaying the human readable character for size. It's displaying in plain total Byte

Comment: Do you have numfmt?

Comment: numfmt displaying mb as kb. Is this expected ?

Comment: `numfmt displaying mb as kb. Is this expected ?` From `man do`:  `Display values are in units of the first available SIZE from --block-size, and the DU_BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE and BLOCKSIZE environment    
       variables.  Otherwise, units default to 1024 bytes (or 512 if POSIXLY_CORRECT is set).` Anyway, good catch - added `-B 1`

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask the machine to process human data:

```
du -s * | sort -rg
```